# How can I copy rows in a POSTGRESQL table based on an array?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

Hello people of Stack Overflow!

I'm creating an API for my app using nodejs, expressjs and postgresql, and recently came across a niche problem that I haven't been able to find a solution for.

I have tables A and B with respective id's, and table B stores A_id as a Foreign key (so A can "have" multiple B instances). In one of my calls on expressjs, I'm copying some rows in A, making slight changes, then saving them as extra rows in A. Easy - I'm using a INSERT INTO SELECT query. At the end of that query, I'm returning a list of old and new entries in A to use when copying B.

e.g. [{old_A_id: 'exampleid1', new_A_id: 'exampleid2'}, {old_A_id: 'exampleid3', new_A_id: 'exampleid4'}, ...]

Copying rows in B is where the problem lies. When copying rows in B, I need to make sure every row that has an old A_id is copied, and its A_id now references the new A_id associated with that old A_id. How can I do this without looping through that array and pool.querying every single object in that array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the `INSERT INTO … SELECT` query you're doing on A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just the same, using `INSERT INTO … SELECT`, albeit this time with an extra `JOIN` against the list of copies you've made:

```
client.query(
    `INSERT INTO B (a_id, other)
    SELECT new_a_id, other
    FROM B
    JOIN json_to_recordset($1::json) AS a_mapping(new_a_id text, old_a_id text) ON a_id = old_a_id;`,
    [JSON.stringify(listOfEntries)]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll make sure to try this out and give an update. So I get that "json_to_recordset($1::json) AS a_mapping(new_a_id text, old_a_id text)" would make turn the json into rows of old and new A_id's. But what would it achieve once joined? Is the idea to JOIN this with the SELECT clause so that every a_id that corresponds to an old_A_id is inserting a new_A_id into B(A_id, ...)?

Comment: That's what you want, right? Make a copy of all the Bs that are part of the As that were copied, and make the part of the new As?

Comment: That is exactly what I want! Thanks for the help :) As a sql novice, I find this solution very elegant